# When will Cartographer be packaged with ROS Noetic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, cartographer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently installed ROS Noetic and have found that Cartographer is not packaged with it "out of the box" like in Melodic and therefore needs to be installed from source. Does anyone have any idea whether this might be in the pipeline?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365214/when-will-cartographer-be-packaged-with-ros-noetic?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps not what you came to hear, but: have you asked the maintainers/developers? They are the ones who should release it.

> Cartographer is not packaged with it "out of the box" like in Melodic

pedantic, but Cartographer never "came packaged" with any ROS version.

It's not part of any of the standard variants described in [REP 150](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html) (ROS Melodic and Newer Metapackages), so whether it is available for any ROS version will depend on whether the developers/maintainers have released it.

---

Edit: and according to one of the maintainers (from [cartographer-project/cartographer_ros#1512](https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer_ros/issues/1512)):

> We plan to release for Noetic, but it's not yet fixed when and how we want to do it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-11-11**:
Ok thanks for clearing this up. Much appreciated :)